# Euclidean distance among dictionary elements

Tags: python, dictionary, combinations, euclidean-distance

I am trying to compute the euclidean distance among the dictionary elements as shown below

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import itertools
from scipy.spatial import distance

def Distance(data):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(data, 2):
        print subset
        #This shows a tuple of two element instead of the elements of the dictionary.
        dst = distance.euclidean(subset)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    data = {}

    data['1'] = [5, 3, 4, 4, 6]
    data['2'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    data['3'] = [3, 1, 2, 3, 3]
    data['4'] = [4, 3, 4, 3, 3]
    data['5'] = [3, 3, 1, 5, 4]
    Distance(data)
```

The issue is that when I try to compute the combination of the dictionary elements I get something that I do not expect, as commented in the code. I think I am doing something wrong with itertools.combinations...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're taking combinations of an iteration, and the iteration is:

```
for element in data:
    print(element)
```

If you run that code, I think you'll see the issue:  you're iterating over the keys of the dictionary, not the elements.  Try again with `.values()`:

```
for subset in itertools.combinations(data.values(), 2):
    print subset
```

You have a couple of other issues in your code though:  Firstly `distance.euclidean` takes 2 parameters, so you'll need to do something like this:

```
dst = distance.euclidean(*subset)
```

...or this...

```
dst = distance.euclidean(subset[0], subset[1])
```

...and secondly your function isn't doing anything with `dst`, so it will be overwritten every time through your loop.

Comment: thanks! I stopped because the results was not the expected one. Now I can use the `dst` value for my purpose. A curiosity: what's the meaning of passing `*subset` to the function? thanks again!

Comment: Cool - glad it worked out!  That's a way of passing in multiple parameters.  If you have a list or tuple, you can use that to expand it to a set of arguments.  If you have a dictionary you can do the same thing with named arguments.  Take a look at this part of the python tutorial:  https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions